# Green function derivation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, proof-explanation

My professor derived the free-space dyadic Green function from the general Green function:
$$\tag{1}
\stackrel{\leftrightarrow}{\boldsymbol{G}}=\left[\stackrel{\leftrightarrow}{\mathbb{I}}+\frac{1}{k^{2}} \nabla \nabla\right] G_{0}(R)$$
With the scalar Green function:
$$\tag{2}
G_{0}(R)=\frac{e^{i k R}}{4 \pi R}, \quad R \equiv\left|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}^{\prime}\right|$$
In the derivation, he states the following:
$$\tag{3}
\nabla \hat{\mathbf{R}}=\nabla\left(\frac{\mathbf{R}}{R}\right)=\frac{\nabla \mathbf{R}}{R}+\mathbf{R} \nabla \frac{1}{R}$$
where $\boldsymbol{R}=\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}^{\prime}, \quad \widehat{\boldsymbol{R}}=\frac{\boldsymbol{R}}{R}$. He says we can see from eq. (3) that $\nabla \mathbf{R}=\mathbb{I}$, but I don't see that? Can someone explain how he gets to that conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what is $\nabla \mathbf{R}$? In 3 space, $\mathbf{R} = \{x-x', y-y',z-z'\}$, then $$\nabla \mathbf{R} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\partial_x \\
\partial_y \\
\partial_z \\
\end{bmatrix} \cdot 
[x-x',y-y',z-z']
  $$

Which is a $3 \times 1$ matrix times a $1 \times 3$ matrix which results in a $3 \times 3$ matrix. If you compute this "outer product" you will get the identity matrix.